# how to get id of pending intent, if i added id by FLAG_ONE_SHOT?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarm, android-pendingintent

I am making alarm application and users can add multiple alarms with different louds and ringtones. At broadcast receiver i want to get id(i setted up id at alarmpref activity:

```
 public void setAlarm(Calendar calendar){
    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 86400000, pendingIntent);
    Intent i = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    i.putExtra("id", 1);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

and use it to play selected ringtone and loud. Thank you

Comment: you are passing wron params to `PendingIntent.getBroadcast`, read javadocs again

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to add Extras to Intent object as follows:

```
 public void setAlarm(Calendar calendar){
    int requestCode=100;
    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra("someid",123);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), requestCode, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 86400000, pendingIntent);
}
```

and also there is not need of writing :

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    i.putExtra("id", 1);
    startActivity(i);
```

AlarmReceiver is started automatically when time for alarm is reached.

Comment: i am gonna to randomize id?(in putextra("id", randomize this). And how i am gonna to know which alarm is playing now?

Comment: @Muu `getBroadcast` has wrong parameters, read my comment above